# Git sends huge amount of data after branch

Tags: git, push, remote-branch

I have a repository with lots of binary files (about 250MB) - I don't know if that is important.

I'm making a new branch and trying to publish it on the central server:

```
git checkout -b newbranch
git push origin newbranch:newbranch
```

Now here, git is trying to push 30MB of data to the server.
Why?? There are no changes.

Also tried to make a bundle:

```
git bundle afile master..newbranch
fatal: Refusing to create empty bundle.
```

What is wrong?

Comment: that is interesting. good question mode (the bundle example is really good for proving the context)

Comment: And `origin` is really the remote repository you retrieved the orginal branch from?

Comment: It is the original repo I cloned from.

Comment: I tried git gc, git prune to no avail. Plain old diff shows that a newly cloned repo (from the same server) differs in .git/logs/ and both repos have large (210MB) files inside the .git/objects/pack dir, and that files are different (name and content). Is there any command I could inspect the differences with?

Comment: I gave up - I created a new remote, exactly identical to the origin, a told git to fetch it. Almost no data was downloaded. Then I created a local branch out of it (new_master), and another branch (new_copy). I could successfully push the new_copy to the server without sending any large amount of data over network (using the new remote) Still it would nice to know what was wrong with the original remote.

Comment: which operating system and git version is the client?

Comment: I also created a branch, made two small commits and when I pushed the branch in the server, there was a lot of data sent.

Comment: I experienced almost the same now, in my case I did branch, a few commits in the branch, then push ... and transfer was 250 MB, which looks like the whole repository. The git output was: `Writing objects: 100% (35142/35142), 250.63 MiB | 47.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 35142 (delta 14452), reused 34619 (delta 14347)`

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34888813/2303202) could be a reason

Comment: @max630 This seems very likely. I encountered it several times again, I aborted the push which took very long and each time there was a new commit in the remote master, and as soon as I fetched it, the push was done as expected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why did git push so much data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34820019/why-did-git-push-so-much-data)

Answer (score 0):

It's to do with the way git stores the data and how a push works. I'm guessing that pushing the new branch is not what's causing the data transfer but a previous commit that's also missing from origin is being pushed as well.

This is why git's a very bad idea for log files - I tend to add them to the .gitignore file so they never get committed, even by mistake :)

Comment: a bit of smoke and mirrors tactics there

Comment: No, a new checkout with a new remote has the same HEAD hash as the existing one, so one commits were outstanding.

Comment: no commits are outstanding _for that branch_ - that doesn't mean that there definitely aren't objects in your repository that aren't in the remote, it just means that they aren't part of your new branch.

Comment: Ok I understand the reasoning - maybe there were some objects - but where did they come from (the HEAD was the same)? And how I can check what is inside those objects?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe not a useful answer, but I tried this exact thing, and git didn't send up any objects.  So maybe there was a commit in there, and you didn't realize it.