# Is it possible to move a shallow history from one git repository to another?

Tags: git, depth

My goal is to take the last few months worth of commits from a repo with many years of history, and start over in a fresh repo.

I have read the questions which sound familiar, and am only a journeyman in Git, so I still have not found a way that works.

It is easy to **fetch** a limited history, but all attempts so far to **push** that result to a remote fail with the same error:

> > error: unpack failed: error Missing commit c709b....
> >     ! [remote rejected] develop -> develop (n/a (unpacker error))

I had read that **push**es from a shallow clone are supported after git 1.9, but my client and server are both running newer versions of git, and still no luck.

Comment: Do you want the resulting repo to still be shallow, so that the original history can be pulled in later if you want? Or do you want to cut out the old history completely?

Comment: it might help to fetch prior to push, because if same reason as here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34888813/2303202

Comment: I wish to discard the history altogether (well, leave it in the existing repo, and push the newly truncated history into a new repo)